# how to read c++ iso standard? i mean the way

Tags: c++, grammar, iso, unordered-set

I'm reading n4860 now and i have some curiosity about this.

i don't know how to explain it so i will just show an example.

now i'm looking "unordered_set" and the draft said

```
template<class Key,
    class Hash = hash<Key>,
    class Pred = equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = allocator<Key>>
class unordered_set;
```

and i infer that when i make custom Key class then i should make hash, equal_to, allocator class and fill it to container work rightly.

but i can't find what should be filled in classes.

for example, if i make custom Key class and i have to make Hash class with operator(const Key& key) method, and Pred class with operator(const Key& key1, const Key& key2) method.

and another example, Hash class with operator(const Key& key) should return size_t or may be unsigned long int(?) not like string.

i can find that information with web searching and compiler error message, but i can't find on draft.

does draft has no information about like that? or i miss that information because i don't know how to read it?

Comment: The standard defines the language, but does not teach you how to use it. I would recommend [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: If needed you must provide template specializations for hash<> and equal_to<> (allocator I think usually is fine). 

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash.

Comment: then, how book authors and web contributers can know about it?

Comment: Here are requirements for hash: https://eel.is/c++draft/utility.requirements#hash.requirements, the predicate should be somewhere in this section as well

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thanks. i should read about it

Comment: You don't have to provide `Hash`, `Pred` or `Allocator` if `std::hash<Key>`, `std::equal_to<Key>` and `std::allocator<Key>` exist and do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements for `std::unordered_map` are listed in C++20 draft in section [22.2.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/unord.req). The requirements for Hash are stated in 22.2.7.1.3 as:

> Each unordered associative container is parameterized by Key, by a function object type Hash that meets the Cpp17Hash requirements ([hash.requirements]) and acts as a hash function for argument values of type Key, and by a binary predicate Pred that induces an equivalence relation on values of type Key.
> Additionally, unordered_­map and unordered_­multimap associate an arbitrary mapped type T with the Key.

With [hash.requirements] being in [16.4.4.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/hash.requirements) section of this standard.

Pred requirements are in [22.2.7.1.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/unord.req#general-5):

> Two values k1 and k2 are considered equivalent if the container's key equality predicate pred(k1, k2) is valid and returns true when passed those values.
> If k1 and k2 are equivalent, the container's hash function shall return the same value for both.

---

In general, looking up different requirements in standard is infeasible (unless you are working on a compiler or a resource based on standard like cppreference). It is not really meant for that, because it must be a legal document which takes into account every possibility. I suggest using cppreference instead. Going from page `std::unordered_map` we can see that it must meet [*UnorderedAssociativeContainer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnorderedAssociativeContainer) requirements, which direct us to pages about [*Hash*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Hash) requirement and to [*BinaryPredicate*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BinaryPredicate) requirement.

Comment: now i see cppreference looks easier than iso document. thanks!